# Ошибка вычисления длины строки wchar_t

Tags: c

Делаю автозагрузку приложения, проблема в lstrlenW(appPath), она не вычисляет полную длину строки, отбрасывает несколько последних символов.

```
// Получаем путь к приложению
wchar_t appPath[32767];
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, appPath, 32767);

// Заполняем путь в реестре
wchar_t *autorunPath = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
wchar_t *appName = L"CApplication.exe";

// Объявляем ключ
HKEY hKey = NULL;

// Записываем в реестр
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, autorunPath, 0, KEY_WRITE, &hKey);
RegSetValueExW(hKey, appName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)appPath, lstrlenW(appPath));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте `wcslen`

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Так же теряется часть пути.

Comment: На кибере объяснили, в чем дело: http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1394490.html#post7339015